# Problem with Hyperic monitoring on CloudFoundry - frequent alerts

Tags: alerts, cloud-foundry, hyperic

I'm running single instance CloudFoundry configuration with one web application. I turned on Hyperic monitoring with notification for case of web app unavailability.

Now I randomly receive alert emails (Subject "An alert has been triggered - Deployment myapp - context unavailable") that the application is not running, but it obviously is running fine.

In access log of Apache I see two requests every 15 seconds:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2010:15:37:33 +0100] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 438 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2010:15:37:33 +0100] "GET /myapp HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
```

At the time when I get the alert emails, everything in log still seems to be fine - two requests.

Do you have idea what could be wrong? Did anybody have this kind of problem and solve it?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got info from CloudFoundry guys. The alerts are sent if either Apache or internal Tomcat request goes wrong or is timeouted. My problem apparently came from internal Tomcat requests that are not logged in access log.

They now simply changed the algorithm, so the alert is trigerred when unavailability (Apache / Tomcat) is reported at least two times in a row. Frequent alert emails problem is gone.